# Install sh file command not found

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

Hi I'm 100 percent new to linux and ssh.  I'm currently having trouble getting a command to run via ssh on my raspberry pi 3.  The operating system I have installed is OSMC.  I've been following the instructions laid out here: https://zatarranl.wordpress.com/2017/01/08/howto-setup-a-spotify-connect-web-server-on-a-raspberry-pi-with-osmc/ and I'm at step 4.  This is where I've run into trouble.  The commands listed:

```
curl -O curl -OL https://github.com/Fornoth/spotify-connect- 
web/releases/download/0.0.3-alpha/spotify-connect-web.sh3
chmod u+x spotify-connect-web.sh
./spotify-connect-web.sh install
```

None of the commands past the first work unless I changed the reference to the sh file from spotify-connect-web.sh to spotify-connect-web.sh3.  Still the last command doesn't seem to be working.  It gives me this error message when performed:

```
 ./spotify-connect-web.sh3: line 1: Not: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site that you got the instructions from displays a number following each link in the article for some reason. As a result, you have an erroneous number at the end of your URL, and you're getting a 404 "Not found" error from GitHub when you try to access the URL. Curl is writing the words "Not found" into its output file, and you're trying to execute the resulting file as a shell script:

```
bash-3.2$ curl -O curl -OL https://github.com/Fornoth/.../spotify-connect-web.sh3
curl: Remote file name has no length!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100     9    0     9    0     0     44      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    44
bash-3.2$ ls
spotify-connect-web.sh3
bash-3.2$ cat spot*
Not Found
```

Removing the "3" from the end produces the result that you're probably expecting:

```
bash-3.2$ curl -O curl -OL https://github.com/Fornoth/.../spotify-connect-web.sh
                                                                                ^- no "3"
curl: Remote file name has no length!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   612    0   612    0     0   2334      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2335
100   531  100   531    0     0   1050      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1050
bash-3.2$ ls
spotify-connect-web.sh
bash-3.2$ head spot*
#!/bin/bash
set -e

DIR=~/spotify-connect-web-chroot
...
```

I will also note that the version of the spotify-connect-web script that you're trying to download is out of date. See [this page](https://github.com/Fornoth/spotify-connect-web/releases).

Comment: I made sure to check out the updated file as I recommend all who find this post do.  Thank you.